# StaleElementReferenceException when iterating through buttons/tiles on a page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am webscraping https://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet_devices and as one selects a phone and proceeds to select a plan as a 'new customer' there are often two or three buttons: 'premium ultra', 'premium plus', etc. I have gotten the css selector to those tiles but as I get to the third iteration I get a 'StaleElementReferenceException'.

I have already put into place try/exceptions however I would prefer to get through all the tiles as the next part of my code involves iterating through the 'plan and data options' below.

```
        plantypes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#prod-term-radio .hot-tile')

        print(len(plantypes)) #number of plan types.

        for plan in plantypes:
            try:

                plan.click()
                time.sleep(3)


            except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
                pass
```

I would like to be able to iterate through all of the tiles instead of prematurely cutting out after the second.

Answer (score 1):

You have to refresh your element list after click because the `DOM` has updated, causing the elements to go stale, try this;

```
plantypes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#prod-term-radio .hot-tile')        
print(len(plantypes)) #number of plan types.

for count, plan in enumerate(plantypes):
    try:
        ptypes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#prod-term-radio .hot-tile') 
        ptypes[count].click()
        time.sleep(3)

    except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        pass
```